# Highlight rows where Month column is equal to today's month

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a choice column (it can be a text column if that would work) called Month, with options for Jan to Dec.

I am trying to use column formatting to highlight rows where the chosen month is the same as the current month.

This is without a date column, or the Created column.

I have looked into the @now function but I am still stuck! any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be easier if you use choices 1 to 12 for months while using "getMonth()" operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON view formatting for this. Use choices from 1 to 12 in "Month" column and then use below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(Number([$Month]) == getMonth(@now) + 1, 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', '')"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [view-list-formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting)

Comment: For using January to December as text choices, you will require complex calculations in JSON.

Comment: This works great thanks! Although, for me it is seeing October as number 9 (I am guessing 0 = January, rather than 1). How did yours work so that 10 = October instead of 9 = October?

Comment: I pasted the wrong JSON earlier. I have corrected it now, check updated answer.